# Jquery radio button cannot set value to lower value via code

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have a group of radio buttons similar to the following:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="GroupTypeOffUnitOnUnit" value="0">1:1</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="GroupTypeOffUnitOnUnit" value="1">Option</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="GroupTypeOffUnitOnUnit" value="2">Other Option</label>
```

I am retrieving values over AJAX, and I have confirmed that the values coming back are correct. However, when I try to programmatically set the value to a value that is less than the current value for example the current value is 2 and i try to set it to 1 the the selected radio button remains the button with 2. On the other hand, if the currently selected radio button has a value of 1 I can then set it to two.

I feel this may have something to do with the order in which the buttons occur on the web page as the higher values come after the lower values, but I am trying to figure it out. 
Also, here is my javascript function that is supposed to check the new value.

```
function setRadioInputValue(targetid, name, value)
{
   $("#" + targetid + " input[name=" + name + "][value=" + value + "]").attr('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first set all the target input's radio button's `checked` value to false and THEN set the one you're wanting as true. Otherwise the 'highest' (or furthest child) value set to `true` will show as checked.

Something like this:

```
function setRadioInputValue(targetid, name, value) {
    $("#" + targetid + "input[name=" + name + "]").each(function(it) {
        it.attr('checked', false);
    });
    $("#" + targetid + " input[name=" + name + "][value=" + value + "]").attr('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing extra apostrophes.
Try this:

```
function setRadioInputValue(targetid, name, value) {
   $("#" + targetid + " input[name='" + name + "'][value='" + value + "']").attr('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking it through, I decided to trigger a click on the specific radio button, so the call should select the radio button then trigger the .click() function like so:

```
$("#" + targetid + " input[name=" + name + "][value=" + value + "]").click();
```